# Awk add '\t' to output file after inserting a column

Tags: bash, awk

I'm using awk to insert a new column in a tab-delimited file, then I want the output to be tab-delimited.  However, instead of the expected 5 tab-delimited columns, I'm only getting 2.

```
 awk -v var=$REL_TYPE -F "\t" '{$3=var FS $3 ;}1' $INPUT_FILE > OFS="\t" $OUTPUT_FILE
```

here is input data:

```
 a1000  a1001   213 1
 a1000  a7020   164 2
 a1000  a6004   160 3
 a1000  a7004   124 4
```

here is the output data:

```
 a1000  a1001 inserted_column   213 1
 a1000  a7020 inserted_column   164 2
 a1000  a6004 inserted_column   160 3
 a1000  a7004 inserted_column   124 4
```

At first glance, this looks perfect, however the output has only two columns delimited by '\t', after $3.

Comment: `OFS="\t"` is the output file you're redirecting to, it's not being used as an awk variable assignment.

Comment: You also need to do the assignment to `OFS` *before* you read your input file for it to be in effect for output generated for the input file. So `awk -v ... -F ... 'script...' OFS='\t' "$INPUT_FILE" > "$OUTPUT_FILE"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting `OFS` correctly. Putting the assignment after `>` makes it the output file to write to, so it's not parsed as a variable assignment. The following works:

```
awk -v var=$REL_TYPE -v OFS="\t"  -F "\t" '{$3=var FS $3 ;}1' $INPUT_FILE > $OUTPUT_FILE
```